# How can I get App Engine's custom 404 page working?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've tried every combination of this I can think of:

```
error_handlers:
- file: error.html
```

Before the handlers block, after the handlers block, with the file in a folder, with the file at the root, with a `url: /*` handler, without a `url: /*` handler, with spaces in front of `- file`, without spaces in front of `-file`, in the 1.6 SDK, in production... it never works.  Not for URLs that are not matched by app.yaml, not for URLs that are matched but not handled, not for URLs that match non-existent static files.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404s are not handled by [custom error handler](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses) pages. If you want 404s to be handled by a static page, you'll need to define a handler that returns the 404 with the appropriate error code - something your framework probably already does for you when it gets URLs that don't map to anything.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll add handle what I can in code, and ignore `static_dir` blocks.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spacing used in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses):

```
error_handlers:
  - file: default_error.html
```

and make sure your URLs are *really* not matched in app.yaml by, say, a handler for `.*` and that your error page itself isn't matched by a static file handler.

Comment: "Not found error: /does-not-exist did not match any patterns in application configuration."